# Doing subquery with list of Ids using Dapper 1.50 and Oracle 18

Tags: oracle, dapper

All,
   I am  sending a list of Ids( More than the max of 1000 allowed by Oracle) in the sql where clause using Dapper 1.50 and Oracle 18. Since there is a limit on the number of items in the in clause, I decided to do a sub query as below but I can't get this to working. Can someone shed some light on this. I will always be sending more than 1000 items as Ids. The second sql statement is not working( It says invalid sql).

```
public static List<Notes> GetNotes()
        {


            List<Notes> notes = new List<Notes>();
            try
            {               
                using (var connection = OracleConnectionString)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    string idCommand = @"select * from (select
    id
from
    note_text
order by
    1
desc)where
    rownum <=2000";

                    var notesList = connection.Query<Notes>(idCommand);
                    var noteIds1 = notesList .Select(i => i.id).ToList();                   


                    string command = @"select
                                               tnt.id as id,
                                               tnt.NOTE_TXT
                                                          from
                                                             note_text tnt
                                                             (
                                                                select
                                                                    note_id
                                                                 from
                                                                      dual
                                                                where
                                                                    note_id in :noteIds1
                                                              )x where x.note_id = tnt.id";

                    var info = connection.Query<Notes>(command, new
                    {
                        noteIds1

                    });
                    notes = info.ToList();

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return notes;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does this list of id's originate?  I'd get them into a file that can be accessed as an external table. Then, instead of

```
select ...
from ...
where id in (<listthatstoolong)
```

you would

```
select ...
from ...
where id in (select id from id_external_table)
```

Then you are not limited to a size of a string of elements in your IN list.

Comment: The list of ids are coming from a third party service in the real application. I dont want to insert those into at le first and do an inner join. So my only option would be to make multiple queries if its more than 1k?

Comment: What's your objection to putting them in a file and doing an inner join?  That's the cleanest solution.  That's like saying you have a flat tire but don't want to use the spare tire, jack, and lug wrench the manufacturer packed in the trunk for that very purpose.